# Initializing numpy array of zeros using for loop

Tags: python, syntax

I require to create a list of numpy arrays with zeros to accomplish something as follows.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros([10,1])
b = np.zeros([10,1])
c = np.zeros([10,1])
d = np.zeros([10,1])
e = np.zeros([10,1])
```

Therefore, I created a list of variable names and ran a for loop as follows

```
list = ['a', 'b' , 'c', 'd' , 'e']
for i in list:
    i = np.zeros([10,1])
```

I know I am wrong or missing something while doing the above steps. Can someone tell me what's the mistake and a proper way to do it?

Comment: You are assigning array to a string instead of variable.

Answer (score 2):

Best way is to use dictionary:

```
list = ['a', 'b' , 'c', 'd' , 'e']
mydict = {}
for i in list:
    mydict[i] = np.zeros([10,1])



>>>mydict['a']
array([[ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.],
       [ 0.]])
```

With your previous statement : `i  = np.zeros([10,1])` , you were just reassigning value of `i` to the numpy array and not actually assigning the array to the "variable", like below :

```
list = ['a', 'b' , 'c', 'd' , 'e']
mydict = {}
for i in list:
    i= np.zeros([10,1])
print i 


[[ 0.]
 [ 0.]
 [ 0.]
 [ 0.]
 [ 0.]
 [ 0.]
 [ 0.]
 [ 0.]
 [ 0.]
 [ 0.]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Would you be fine with using a dictionnary?

```
Dict = {}

list = ['a', 'b' , 'c', 'd' , 'e']
    for i in list:
       Dict[i] = np.zeros([10,1])
```

The various `i` are you dictionnary keys now, so after the for loop you can retrieve the desired array using `a = Dict["a"]`. I'm sure there is a more elegant solution though.

Answer (score 0):

you can use following code that init it in inline dictionary

```
  mydict = { i:np.zeros([10,1]) for i in ['a', 'b' , 'c', 'd' , 'e']  }

    print(mydict['a'])
```